# Sveltekit data-preloads : does it prevent two same data-preloads of the same page?

Tags: sveltekit

I occasionally use [preload attribues](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/link-options) in Sveltekit

```
data-sveltekit-preload-code="eager"
data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover"
```

In a same page, I might happen to have two `<a>` with the same `href` and `data-sveltekit-preload-*` attributes,

Will Sveltekit pre-load the page/code only once ? Or twice ?

Comment: I was wandering the same. Even more SvelteKit shoudl  preload page only once (on the first hover of the same link) which seems not to be the case.